# What is the purpose of installing frontend libraries on Node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm

I understand that when we talk about the frontend we're talking about files being served to the browser of the person accessing my page. So, frontend javascript libraries are only javascript code that is being sent from my server to the browser.

So far everything is fine, what I don't understand is why `npm` has repositories for frontend libraries. Let's take this [Leaflet example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet), I can install this library with npm using `npm install leaflet -s`. But what would be the purpose of doing that? I see that if I open Visual Studio Code and I declare this library with `const leaflet = require('leaflet')` then I can see its functions and documentation in a more clear way on the suggestions after typing `leaflet.`... I don't think that's the purpose of installing a library like Leaflet on Node.js though (since it works only on the frontend). What am I missing? Why would anyone install frontend only libraries on Node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are likely other reasons, but this is they reason I've done it and the reason I've seen other people do it: Many people use Node.js tooling to bundle/build webapps, so you might install your frontend dependencies, and then use `rollup` or `webpack` or `browserify` or TypeScript tooling or whatever to bundle it into a single `.js` file. Since you're likely already installing the tooling with `npm`, installing the libraries also with `npm` means you don't need some *other* tool to do it.

Additionally, people also use `npm` to install libraries for `electron` apps, `cordova` apps, `React Native` apps, etc. And these things can all use frontend libraries because they basically have a web view embedded. (To be honest, I'm not sure that's the case with `React Native` because I've never used it, but I assume it is.)

Since you mention Leaflet specifically, [here is an example of someone using `npm` to install `leaflet`](https://github.com/renelikestacos/Web-Mapping-Leaflet-NodeJS-Tutorials), and then using `browserify` to make it so that they can basically write Node.js code (including `require('leaflet')` and run it in the browser.

Comment: I see, so it's a matter of building the frontend with libraries that are installed on the system. Well, I think this question sounded too  basic for people who are good at front-end development. In my case, I always used the old html, javascript and css files served with apache for doing only simple stuff. One thing that botters me on doing development this way is that I don't see recommendations of functions from libraries when I'm working with files on a folder only. I guess using the framework solutions like `React` or `Vue` solve this problem with the extra steps that they involve. Thanks